# Structuring Media Queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, fluid-layout

I am trying to structure my media queries from the lowest to the highest resolution. But I am sure I am missing something very silly here. Please have a look:

**FLUID STYLE SHEET:**

```
@media ( max-width : 360px){

    .flicker-nav{
        top:2px;
        min-height: 40px;
    }
}

@media  ( min-width: 361px ) and ( max-width: 480 px ) 
and (orientation: landscape) {

    .flicker-nav{
        top:3px;
        min-height: 60px;
    }
}

@media ( min-width: 361px ) and ( max-width: 480 px ) 
and ( orientation:portrait ) {
    .flicker-nav{
        top:3px;
        min-height: 50px;
    }
 }
@media  ( min-width: 481px ) and ( max-width: 768 px ) 
and ( orientation: landscape ) {
    .flicker-nav{
        top:3px;
        min-height: 60px;
    }
 }

@media ( min-width: 481px ) and ( max-width: 768 px ) 
and ( orientation: portrait ) {
    .flicker-nav{
        top:2px;
        min-height: 40px;

    }
 }
@media  ( min-width: 769 px ) and ( max-width: 1280 px ) {
    .flicker-nav{
        top:4.5px;
        min-height: 75px;
    }
}

@media ( min-width: 1281 px ) and ( max-width: 1440 px ) {
    .flicker-nav{
        top:5px;
        min-height: 80px;
    }
 }
@media ( min-width: 1441 px )  {
    .flicker-nav{
        top:8px;
        min-height: 100px;

    }
 }
```

**THE NORMAL STYLE SHEET:**

```
.flicker-nav {
    z-index: 500;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

I am also re-sizing the parent div on every screen resize using the following JS:

**JS:**

```
function reset_demensions() {
    doc_height = $(window).height();
    doc_width = $(window).width();
    $(".flicker-div").css("min-width", doc_width + "px");
    $(".flicker-div").css("min-height", doc_height + "px");
 }
$(document).ready(function() {
    reset_demensions();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $.doTimeout('resize', 350, function() {
            reset_demensions();
        });

    });

});
```

But after all these **no matter how I resize the window no content of the fluid sheet is reflected in the browser**. On deeper investigation I found that the browser is reading the fluid file differently ( must have some syntactical error ) apart from the first query

```
@media ( max-width : 360px){ }
```

it is read all the others as

```
@media not all { }
```

Please help me figure this out. I am really sorry for such a long post but I really wasn't able to make it any shorter.

Comment: do you have a URL we could look at?

Comment: No , I didn't host it yet. working locally as of now.

Comment: I can just try and make a demo of it and host it .. if you want me to ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of validation errors.  The [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) says that the only valid piece of code is this:

```
@media ( max-width : 360px){
    .flicker-nav{
        top:2px;
        min-height: 40px;
    }
}
```

It looks like most of the problems stem from the spaces before your units (eg. `1281 px` should be `1281px`)

> only 0 can be a length. You must put a unit after your number  and ( max-width: 1440 px ) { .flicker-nav{ top:5px; min-height: 80px; } }

Comment: oh crap .. such a silly mistake and I have been scratching  at this for hours now.. Thanks a TONS !! you just saved my life..